# Report works on development PC but throws exception on the PC where it's deployed (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument)

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I developed an application with Crystal Reports, when i test the project on the development PC it works, but it gives an exception on the customer PC

> **The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception.**

also the project was developed Using VS 2010 then it completed with VS 2008,so I am developing using VS 2008 now, I'm not sure if this Could Cause the problem, and about the **Setup Project** i make a reference to the following DLLs:

```
-CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
-CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
-CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
-CrystalDecisions.Web.dll
-CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
```

All DLLs have the same version number :10.2.3600.0

And i install the setup without installing anything else then .net Framework 3.5, (Do i have to install a runtime Crystal Report engine and if have to which version to install? ).

Exception Details:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Thanks in advance for any Help.

Comment: Hi, can you please post the details of the Exception (if any) - IMHO this looks like some version-problem with CR. We have those a lot in our company (there are some external products using CR and some internal Apps - it's always a pain to get both CR-versions working on the same machine) - that is the reason why we tend to not using CR anymore

Comment: You can test this by installing the product on a fresh (virtual if possible) PC!

Comment: ok thank i will try Find Details and reply ASAP

Comment: oh - one more thing - there should be a merge(r?)-module for CR that you should add to your setup, inside this merge-module you have to set some property to you used licence-number (you can find this under Help/About... inside VS and then choosing CR-item in the list)

Comment: @Carsten which file should i add to the merge module ?
is it one of these files ?
Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC80_DebugMFC_x86_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86_x64.msm

Comment: sorry again (it's a long time I did this) - seems like starting with 2008 SAP got it's hands on CR (thought it was only with VS2010) - so you have to get it from SAP - see here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2009/01/26/crystal-reports-merge-modules-for-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Comment: you should find it under Crystal Reports for VS.NET 2008 and I guess its the Redistributable

Comment: I've added the exception details above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client's machine you need to install the Crystal Runtime for your version. Normally if you are using VS2008 you need to install Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime Package for the .NET Framework (recommended), or embed the Merge Modules for Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime into your own setup (not recommended). From here: http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#08
That will install Crystal Report's assemblies needed on the client. Have you done that already?

If after that you still have problems, you need to verify that the Crystal.*.dll has the same version than the ones installed on the client's machine.

If you want to use specific version of the crystal assemblies on the properties of those assemblies change the Specific Version to True in the Properties within VS

Finally, check if you are missing a Crystal SP/HotFix which makes the assemblies version differ 
http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+SPs+and+FPs

Comment: Thank you very much I've already solved my problem by Changing my DLLs version to 10.5.*.* instead of 10.2.3600.0 and install the 'Crystal Report runtime' on the client machine.

>If after that you still have problems, you need to verify that the >Crystal.*.dll has the same version than the ones installed on the >client's machine. 
Do you mean the DLLs in the application project references and the DLLs int The Setup Project assemblies ?

Is there a reason to make adding merge modules recommended than its not able to be separately updated cause i thinking to use this way instead.

Comment: Excellent you solved your problem. It is not recommended to embed the crystal merges because it will increase a lot the size of your setup installed. Also, it is what sap/crystal recommends because in case of updates on the runtime you do not need to re-do your setup again.

Comment: you are right, i agree with you using redistributable runtime utility (MSI) is more sufficient, its smaller in size, easier to deploy and can be separately updated.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Crystal Report will call that DLL to create the report.

This is what happened to me, I run on win 10 - 64 bit, and use old application.

Error appeared on app :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried to install CRRedist2005_X64.msi, but the error is still occured, but saying something different.
I have tried to install newer version, but it is useless.

You need to install this :

[**CRRedist2005_x86.msi**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cims2/downloads?page=3)

Make sure the version of dll file.

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.2.3600.0
```

is for CR2005. Maybe higher version is for newer CR version.