# Crystal report not working in client enviroinment,how to resolve this exception?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

[image]

Even I am installed (CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_17) version both client machine and developer machine also.

Comment: Check  the  Crystal Runtime version on client. Also take a look at the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305577/report-works-on-development-pc-but-throws-exception-on-the-pc-where-its-deploye

Comment: Thanks for your reply,how can i change my dll version?

Comment: Is it working in developer environment ? If so then install the same Runtime package as the developer environment.

Comment: working fine in developer machine. I am installed same engine both client and development machine?but its not working.i think so may be need to install frame work .net framework 2.0?

Comment: framework sshould be already there I guess.

Comment: Thanks for ur all replies,i resolved my issue its working.problem is  target famework is AnyCpu,i am changed 64 bit target fame work.